# Jenkins inheritance plugin jobs are run in infinite loop

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins

I'm currently having an issue with running a few jobs in Jenkins CI.
I first will explain my infrastructure of the Jenkins system: 
1. Jenkins Version: 1.627 
2. Using for the current setup the following plug-ins: 
* inheritance plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/inheritance-plugin
3. I have a top job A that has a few parameters.
4. Job B is a child of job A(inheritances all of job A parameters)
5. Job C & D are children of job B(inheritances all of job A & B parameters)
6. Job C is executing a maven build 
7. Job D is installing the tomcat with relevant war files to a machine.
8. Job B has two triggers to run first job C and wait for it to complete and then do the same for job D.
9. All of my nodes are created on the fly using the docker plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin

This is were I have the problem!
If the "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" under the "Trigger/call builds on other projects" section option is selected when calling a job, then job B starts job C as expected, but job C starts bu pulling the Git source and then after that start again the B job!! That means that I'm stuck in an infinite loop of a job calling himself over again.
As soon as I will disable the "Block" option, the job runs normally.

However I do need this option to be enabled because I need to first finish job C in order to start job D.

True example: Job C is called Build. This is a part of the log of that job console:

```
 checking out Revision 03207bc49c5812f7e64f4e2dfafdf3de4cb59376 (origin/SwmOnlineHelp-v10.2)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 03207bc49c5812f7e64f4e2dfafdf3de4cb59376
 > git rev-list 03207bc49c5812f7e64f4e2dfafdf3de4cb59376 # timeout=10
[Build] $ /bin/bash -e /tmp/hudson8040843434464635378.sh
[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties file path 'tmp.properties'
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
Waiting for the completion of Build
```

As you can see job Build is waiting for completion of job Build(paradox/recursive...you call it!)

Does anyone has any idea regarding this issue and how to fix that?